# Policeman, aborted ordination, visions, war in Heaven, angels

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie, but can really just remember one scene.

The main character is (I *think*) a policeman or private detective.  However, he had studied to become a catholic priest.  But on the day of his ordination as priest - as he lay prone on the floor and other priests are doing the ritual - he had terrible visions of a war in Heaven among angels... so he abort his calling.  Someone comments to him that most who doesn't become priests does it because they lacked faith - but he dropped out because he had too much.

I don't really remember anything else, but I assume there is a war in Heaven and that it spills over onto Earth, and that the main character had to stop it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is [The Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prophecy):

> Thomas Dagget, a seminary student, loses his faith when he is shown disturbing visions of a war between angels. Years later, Thomas is a detective with the Los Angeles Police Department. Two angels fall to Earth: one, Simon, warns Thomas of coming events, before disappearing. The second, Uziel, dies attempting to kill Simon. Investigating the disturbance, Thomas finds in Simon's apartment an obituary for a recently deceased Korean War veteran named Arnold Hawthorne and a theology text he wrote. In Chimney Rock, Arizona, Simon finds the veteran and removes the soul from the body. (Source Wikipedia)

Comment: Yes, that's the one.